# What means `Unrecognized error code: COMMAND_FAILED` in Google Smart Home action?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I have built an google smart home action with local fulfilment. It works but sometimes I see the error messages like in example below. How to fix it?  Which part of the google action is throwing this error?

```
{
  "insertId": "************",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "executionLog": {
      "executionResults": [
        {
          "latencyMsec": "286",
          "requestId": "9483989091939510732",
          "actionResults": [
            {
              "status": {
                "statusType": "INVALID_JSON",
                "isSuccess": false,
                "fallbackToCloud": true,
                "externalDebugString": "Unrecognized error code: COMMAND_FAILED"
              },
              "action": {
                "trait": "TRAIT_ON_OFF",
                "actionType": "ONOFF_ON"
              },
              "device": {
                "deviceType": "LIGHT"
              }
            }
          ],
          "executionType": "PARTNER_LOCAL"
        }
      ]
    },
    "locale": "en-US"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "assistant_action_project",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "*********"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-02-23T17:51:24.331526320Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/************/logs/assistant_smarthome%2Fassistant_smarthome_logs",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-02-23T17:51:24.331526320Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what your execution request is sending - there might be typo on the device command.

The [project logs in Cloud Logging](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/monitoring-logging?hl=en#smart_home_events) should also provide you with more detailed information to track down the specific error.